# How to display selected attribute value first in dropdown using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to display selected attribute value default in drop-down by using jQuery,  attribute is assigning but value is not showing default, below is my code, It always showing Select Status only

```
<div class="selector full-width">
                    <select id="sector_status" name="sector_status">
                        <option value="">-----Select Status-----</option>
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Active</option>
                        <option value="2">Inactive</option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select">-----Select Status-----</span>
                </div>
```

`$("#sector_status option[value="+Status+"]").attr("selected","selected");`

Comment: Consider using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` when selecting the value of a property such as `selected`.  Documentation here:  http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qasmsa0j/) it works

Comment: See my updated answer. It will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display selected value of drop down use `change()` function

```
 $('#sector_status').change(function(){
        var selected_val = $('#sector_status :selected').text(); //Get selected text 
        $(".custom-select").text(selected_val); //Replace selected text 
    });
```

To get the currently selected text use `text()` function

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/qasmsa0j/1/

Comment: use `.prop()`? your answer is using `.attr()` which is which?

Comment: Sorry now Updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
$("#edit_alert_destinations"+count+" option[value='"+value.destination+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```